# Указание нескольких шаблонов для grep

Tags: bash, grep

Подскажите, пожалуйста. В мануале по grep указано: "PATTERNS is one or more patterns separated by newline characters" или "PATTERNS - это один или несколько шаблонов, разделенных символами новой строки", но получается, что разделение символами новой строки работает только для случая когда PATTERNS перечислены в файле?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В файле, который вы указываете в ключе `-f`,
шаблоны разделяются переносами строк. Чтобы указать
несколько шаблонов при вызове через аргументы, используйте
несколько ключей `-e`:

```sh
$ grep -e first -e second -- ./file.txt
```

Comment: `grep -E 'pattern1|pattern2...'`

Comment: @0andriy  Это вариант, но он не сработает с флагом `-F`.

Comment: Причём тут `-F`? Ни в вопросе, ни в вашем ответе никакой отсылки к этой опции нет.

Comment: Это комментарий к вашему комментарию.  Вы предложили альтернативу, а я прокомментировал, почему альтернатива сработает не везде.  Да и когда шаблонов много, и все они сложные, лучше использовать отдельные `-e`.